# Mongoid where vs find when using id as criteria

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

when using document's id as the only criteria in my query what's the difference between:

```
Board.only(:_id).find(params[:board_id])
```

and

```
Board.where(_id: params[:board_id]).only(:_id)
```

the only thing i've noticed is that printing the result as json when using where it encloses the result in square brackets

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`find` returns one document.

`where` returns an array of documents that match the criteria.

Answer (score 4):

To add to Kyle's answer:

If matching record is not found: `find` throws exception, `where` returns empty enumerable.

Comment: This behavior depends on Mongoid's raise_not_found_error setting (defaults to true). See http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/installation.html

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers are correct, I'll just add that to find one record without raising an error, the equivalent to `find` is `where.first`. In your case

```
Board.where(_id: params[:board_id]).first.only(:_id)
```